# Wordpress when logged in as admin AJAX call returns 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress, function

When using WordPress **as admin** & calling a WordPress function with AJAX I get **"0"**. But when **logged out as admin**, everything is **working fine**.

Maybe anyone has gotten similar issues like mine and knows a possible fix?

I want that both logged in as admin, and logged out, would return the output (not 0 of course).

This is the function in **functions.php** file.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_category_data', 'getCategoryData');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_get_category_data', 'getCategoryData');

function getCategoryData()
{
    $data = [
    'category' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['category'])
];

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'Coupons',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'CustomCat' ),
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);

$couponBlock = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($data['category']) {
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array ('cat' => $data['category'], 'posts_per_page' => 8) );
    if ($the_query->have_posts()):
        while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template/ajaxCustomCat', 'page');
        endwhile;
        wp_die();
    endif;

} else {
    return 'no data';
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the ajax function as an admin or privileged ajax call as well. So your call should look like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Remember that you're also returning data via **ajax** so a return for AJAX to read is actually an `echo`. So data that needs to be sent back to the frontend should be `echoed` out. If you want to remove the `0` that wordpress sends along with its output, add an `exit()` at the end of your function to signal a finished call.

Comment: Hey. I have updated the topic with my function. As You can see I already have this add_action().. What might be the problem with my code?

Comment: Happy to help! If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as the accepted to close the issue.

Comment: @xoomer accepting an answer is all that you need to do - appreciate it!